# Клиент-сервер, способ обмена обновлениями

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, база-данных, клиент-сервер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный вариант реализации клиент-серверного взаимодействия (если это можно таковым назвать).

Суть: имеем хостинг (сервер) с MySQL и клиент-приложение, при запуске получающее актуальную БД. Через клиент каждый авторизованный пользователь может добавлять/изменять/удалять данные из общей базы на сервере (использую HTTP).

Вопрос: каким образом можно получить список измененных/добавленных строк другим пользователем без перезапуска программы и полной загрузки всей базы?

Например: *Client1 изменил какую-либо запись в БД; Client2, Client3 отправили "getUpdates", получили информацию с этим обновлением и "отрисовали" у себя в интерфейсе*

Спасибо.

**UPD:**

1. Создал таблицу Actions, в которую вношу информацию об изменениях в БД:
   [ Id | Table | Action | RowId | Date ]. При получении "сервером" инфы, вносим название измененной таблицы, произведенное действие, измененную строку и время, в которое это действие было совершено.
2. Создал таблицу Sessions, в которой храню ClientId и UpdatedDateTime.
   Сессию создает сервер при авторизации клиента и передает ClientId клиенту, UpdatedDateTime изначально равен времени входа пользователя.
3. Клиент каждые n-минут посылает запрос к серверу, передавая свой ClientId.
   Получаем UpdatedDateTime по переданному ClientId и делаем выборку из таблицы Actions. *(Actions.Date > Sessions.UpdatedDateTime)*
   Шлём инфу об изменениях клиенту.
4. При получении обновленных данных, клиент добавляет их в свою (локальную) БД и "отчитывается" перед сервером о получении.
5. Сервер получает инфу о том, что клиент обновился и вносит текущее время в UpdatedDateTime. (и возвращаемся к пункту 3)
6. Profit?

Откомментируйте, пожалуйста, нормален ли такой подход к обновлениям?)

Comment: Например, можно добавить колонку `UpdateDateTime` и грузить все записи, обновленные с последнего момента синхронизации.

Comment: ... кстати, MySQL имеет механизм автоматического присвоения значения такому полю при создании/обновлении записи, так что руками ничего делать не потребуется.

Comment: Но в любом случае клиент будет инициативно опрашивать сервер на предмет "а не случилось ли там чего новенького" - MySQL не имеет средств инициативного оповещения клиента о чём-либо.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, ребята! Буду рад за оценку варианта, который я добавил в тему)